# Attachment file display link text

Tags: attachments

This is driving me slightly demented. It's taken me a few hours to work out how to do this and I thought I finally had it, but the link text will only echo the file name and not the link text I want it to. Easy solution is re-name the file to "View Price List", but what if someone further down the line adds a new file and doesn't realise the name has to be the same as the button link text.

I would like the link text to be the same no matter what the name of the attached file is i.e. "Download Price List" or "Pobierz cennik".

```
<?php if( $post->ID == 38) {?>
     <?php $default_strings = array(
            'price_text' => array(
            'en' => 'Download Price List',
            'pl' => 'Pobierz cennik'
            )
        );?>

     <?php
     global $post;
     $args = array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'order'=> 'ASC',
            'post_mime_type' => 'application/msword, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/pdf',
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            'post_status' => 'any',
            'post_type' => 'attachment'
            );

    $attachments = get_posts($args);
            if ($attachments) { ?>
            <?php
            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {?>

            <a class="button big brand-1" <?php echo the_attachment_link($attachment->ID, false); ?>>
            <?php echo $default_strings['price_text'][ $lang ]; ?>
            </a>

            <?php } 
           }?>

          <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the button to:

```
    <a class="button big brand-1" a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, false); ?>">
            <?php echo $default_strings['price_text'][ $lang ]; ?>
    </a>
```

a href is added around the wp_get_attachment_url rather than using the_attachment_link which contains the whole link.